# Why does my SDL app have an abnormal window border on Mac?

Tags: macos, user-interface, window, border, sdl

I've noticed my simple SDL application has an abnormal window border on Mac. There's no gradient and the color is dark gray instead of light gray. It just looks *wrong*. I've noticed that [LÖVE](https://love2d.org/) also has this on mac, and it uses SDL as well, leading me to believe this is indeed SDL-related...
[image]

Meanwhile applications like Finder, Terminal, Audacity... they have a more standard, nice-looking window border.

[image]

Why is this happening, and can I make it look like a normal Mac window?

Answer (score 0):

this is now fixed in [LOVE](https://bitbucket.org/rude/love/issues/1253/title-bar-on-mac-is-sometimes-dark-gray). Looks like the latest SDL source fixes this according to the discussion I linked.